# How to turn echo off in InsertOrReplace?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

When inserting an entity into an Azure Table, I can turn echo off using the second parameter:

```
TableOperation Insert(ITableEntity entity, bool echoContent)
```

Is there a way to turn echo off in InsertOrReplace ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to turn echo off for `InsertOrReplace`, it's off by default, even more than that -  you can't turn it on.

Have a look at [the documentation of `InsertOrReplace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452242.aspx):

> **Status Code**
>   A successful operation returns status code 204 (No Content).

and

> **Response Body**
>   None.

`TableResult.Result` is the same object as passed to `InsertOrReplace` (ReferenceEqual).

This test passes:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test_InsertNew()
    {
        var entity = new SampleEntity("1", "2") {Content = "another initial"};
        var insertOrReplaceOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
        var newItemResponse = table.Execute(insertOrReplaceOperation);
        var returnedEntity = newItemResponse.Result as SampleEntity;
        Assert.Equal((int) HttpStatusCode.NoContent, newItemResponse.HttpStatusCode);
        Assert.Same(entity, returnedEntity); // TableResult.Result and entity we insert is exactly the same instance (ReferenceEqual)
    }
```

`TableOperation` has an internal property [`EchoContent`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Table/TableOperation.Common.cs), this property is used for setting *echo off* for `Insert` operation. Even when you change it using reflection:

```
        insertOrReplaceOperation.GetType().GetProperty("EchoContent",BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(insertOrReplaceOperation, true);
```

you will not get the content back, just status 204 and empty response body.